# Accessing status messages (shared with 'friends') using App Access Token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

Is it possible to get Shared status with friends with an App_Token?

I'm trying to get them but i'm only getting the public ones. I already gave permissions to get user_status, friends_status, user_about_me, publish_stream and read_stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an app access token can only access public data - to access a user's private data you need to use a user access token from that user (or one of their friends which is able to see the content)

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate! So i have to use the extended access_token?